# UseSqlServer() overload without parameters is missing in EF7

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I am reading [this link](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Configuring-a-DbContext) to see various options of configuring EF7 DbContext.

In the section "Connection from config, provider specified in code", it is mentioned that there is an overload of `UseSqlServer()` without any parameters that picks the connection string from the config file of MVC 6 app automatically.

```
options.UseSqlServer();
```

But I can't see this particular overload in the `OnConfiguring()` overridden method. I see only two overloads, one accepting connection string and the other accepting DbConnection.

What am I missing? Is it something not available yet? Am I doing something wrong?

I tried modifying Project.json for EF7 Beta 4, Beta 5 as well as Beta 6. No luck so far.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You've need to define:

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.AddJsonFile("config.json");
configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();`
```

And then:

```
options.UseSqlServer(configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:YourContext"));
```

Comment: No. That's not what I am talking about. As per the link given above there is an overload of UseSqlServer() without any parameters. This overload is supposed to automatically pick the connection string from Config.json (if I understand the document correctly).

Comment: That document is out of date! Notice that it was last edited in May 2015